# Set precedence in text wrapping on different characters in CSS

Tags: css

I'd like to display the path of a file in a column of a table, e.g.

```
some_random_folder/my_long_filename.txt
```

such that when I need to wrap it, it will first wrap at slashes, then at underscores, e.g. showing the column width with "|":

```
|some_random_folder/           |
|my_long_filename.txt          |
```

instead of

```
|some_random_folder/my_long_   |
|filename.txt                  |
```

Of course, if the column is too narrow, it still wraps at underscores:

```
|some_random_    |
|folder/         |
|my_long_        |
|filename.txt    |
```

This is fine too:

```
|some_random_    |
|folder/my_long_ |
|filename.txt    |
```

I know that I can add <kbd><wbr/></kbd> to suggest places to wrap, but that seems to have just one level of priority.

Is that possible with pure CSS? (It's fine if IE/Edge is unsupported.)

Comment: I'm afraid only css can't do this, but a simple javascript can do what you need.

Comment: Thanks, @Esko. How could I do it in Javascript?

Comment: If you're willing to use JavaScript - and you have to, since this isn't possible with CSS - to solve this problem then please [edit] your question to include the JavaScript tag. :)

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done purely in css, so I would suggest using a javascript function for this.

Here is an example using the special html entity `&#8203;` to do a line break that will cut the text if needed. If the line break is not needed it will ***not*** create a visible whitespace.

This is just a basic example that adds line break after the first "/"-character, you can extend it with all the other logic you might need adding more line breaks if you want:

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("cutme");

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  var span = spans[i];
  var index = span.innerText.indexOf("/");
  var text = span.innerText;
  span.innerHTML = text.substring(0, index + 1) + "&#8203;" + text.substring(index + 1);
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cutme">
        some_random_folder/my_long_filename.txt
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cutme">
        folder/filename.txt
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cutme">
        some_random_folder/my_long_filename.txt
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the "some_random_folder/" part is known, `@media all and max-width` can be hacked to wrap white-space (added after underscores as `<wbr />`) below a certain window width. 10em works on my browser in the example below. (It even wraps at character level when the width is under 7em.) I change the colour to show when it starts wrapping.

```css
.wrap { white-space:nowrap; font-family:monospace; }

@media all and (max-width:10em) {
.wrap { white-space:normal; color:blue; }
}

@media all and (max-width:7em) {
.wrap { word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word; color:red; }
}
```

```html
<span class="wrap">some_<wbr />random_<wbr />folder/</span><wbr /><span class="wrap">my_<wbr />long_<wbr />filename.txt</span>
```

Comment: "Run code snippet" doesn't work as it overrides `white-space:nowrap`. Save it as a local file and open it.